# Finding Limits of Integration

Tags: integration, uniform-distribution

I have two functions, one depending on $x$ which is 
$\frac {1} {2} {\delta(x-5)} + \frac {1} {4}$ which is the combination of a dirac delta function at $5$ and a uniform distribution from $5$ to $7$. The second function depends on $x$ and $y$, $ \frac{1} {2}{\delta(y-4-x)} + \frac {1} {4}$ which is a dirac delta function at $x+4$ and a uniform distribution from $x+4$ to $x+6$. Now I'm looking to integrate the product of the two functions.
$\int (\frac {1} {2}{\delta(x-5)} + \frac{1} {4})(\frac{1}{2}{\delta(y-4-x)} + \frac{1}{4})dx$
My question is, how do I determine the limits for this integration?

Comment: Thanks for the correct edit